# Create new column class xlarge

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Foundation comes with default small medium and large classes.

I want to use something like `<div class="small-6 medium-3 large-4 xlarge-2">`

Where xlarge is a media query for screens wider than 1200px.

How can I create this new class?

Thanks!

Comment: Might telling me how this does not fit the stack policies (closing vote..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your settings.scss there is a line of code that you can enable to get these xl classes:

```
$include-xl-html-grid-classes: false; //change to true for xl grid classes
```